# Transforming Table data into new view

Tags: mysql

I has a SQL Query to select below result.

```
    |Port| Type|Size|
    _________________
    |JKT | D40 | 10 |
    |JKT | D50 | 20 |
    |ABC | D30 | 10 |
    |KFC | D50 | 20 |
```

I would like to put the result into the table like below , the JKT,ABC,KFC are not fixed .

```
     |D30 | D40 | D50   <<< this is fix in the table.
JKT  | 0  |  10 | 20
ABC  | 10 |  0  |  0
KFC  | 0  |  0  | 50
```

Im doing this in JSP , because of the environment issue i doing this in the Notepad++ , anyway i just need the logic .Please Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MySql` there is no `Pivot` syntax, so can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
selec port,
      sum(case when type = 'd30' then size else 0 end) as d30,
      sum(case when type = 'd40' then size else 0 end) as d40,
      sum(case when type = 'd50' then size else 0 end) as d50
from table
group by port
```

If there is many ports then you can use `group concat` function. Look for `MySql pivoting`. For example [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Thanks.. i solve it .. im using Switch ,but same logic.